# SFTP upload file Permission denied

Tags: spring, spring-boot, sftp, jsch, spring-integration-sftp

I'm trying to upload excel file using SFTP to linux machine from my local windows PC.

Here is my code:

```
private void uploadToSftp() {
        try
        {
            ChannelSftp sftpClient = null;
            Channel channel = null;
            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            Session session = jsch.getSession("username", "host", 22);
            session.setPassword("password");
            Properties config = new Properties();
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking","no");
            session.setConfig(config);
            session.connect();
            channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
            channel.connect();
            sftpClient = (ChannelSftp) channel;

            sftpClient.cd("/var/www/folder");
            File localFile = new File("C:\\Workspace\\upload-file\\test.xlsx");
            sftpClient.put(localFile.getAbsolutePath(),localFile.getName());

            sftpClient.disconnect();
            channel.disconnect();
            session.disconnect();
        } catch (JSchException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  
        } catch (SftpException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

but every time i run this application i get error:

```
3: Permission denied
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2873)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._put(ChannelSftp.java:594)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.put(ChannelSftp.java:475)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.put(ChannelSftp.java:365)
```

Doesn anyone know what could be problem and how can i solve this?

Comment: Well, it looks like a `Permission denied` error. What credentials and authentication type are you using? Are you sure they're OK?

Answer (score 25):

You seemed to upload your local file **"C:\Workspace\upload-file\test.xlsx"** to remote directory, **"/var/www/folder"** on SFTP.

I guess you have all permissions for **r**eading,**w**riting,**e**xecuting etc on your local file(**"C:\Workspace\upload-file\test.xlsx"**), but your remote folder, **"/var/www/folder"**, might not accept your application's access including "upload" action.

**SOLUTION:**

The most simplest way to solve this issue is just granting all permission for all users to do anything in your upload target directory(**"/var/www/folder"**). Please try this linux commands for checking permission on your upload folder.

```
ls -ld /var/www/folder
```

If you see your **/var/www/folder/** directory is not allowed **w**riting or **r**eading(ex:drwxr-xr-x) for normal users, please grant permissions for this folder with the follwing command.

```
chmod 777 /var/www/folder
//check permission again.
ls -ld /var/www/folder
```

If you can check the target folder's permission is enough(**drwxrwxrwx**), please run your application again.

**NOTE:**
Giving all permissions for other users is not considered a good practice.
Please just do this solution for test, and change the permission setting fit to your specification later. For more detail, [Please check this link(Click).](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_permissions_and_attributes)